# Conexión Firebird php7

Tags: php, apache, firebird

quiero realizar una conexión a firebird por medio de ibase-connect, según la documentación de php esta presente en php 7, pero de momento solo lo he hecho funcionar en php 5.6, necesito hacerlo funcionar con una versión mas reciente de php.

```
$conect_db = ibase_connect($host, $username, $password);
```

donde el host, usuario y contraseña ya lo defino antes, con dicho código solo me dice que la funcion no esta definida, ya he instalado las dll respectivas, modificado el php.ini sin ningún resultado favorable, de antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Establece un control de errores y dinos qué error muestra.

Answer (score 2):

Por si te sirve de orientación, yo utilizo la siguiente sintaxis con php7 y pdo:

```
$host = "localhost";
$bbdd = "YOUR_DB_PATH";
$charset = "utf8";
$userFR = "YOUR_DB_USER";
$passFR = "YOUR_DB_PASSWORD";

$str_conn="firebird:host=".$host.";dbname=".$bbdd.";charset=".$charset;

$dbh = new PDO($str_conn, $userFR, $passFR);

$res=$dbh->query("YOUR_QUERY");
```

Además, tienes que tener en cuenta las siguientes configuraciones en xampp/wampp o el gestor que utilices, ya que la mayoría no vienen preparados para firebird:

1 - Habilitar permisos en el php.ini de librerías:
    Apache->Config->php.ini (descomentar: extension=pdo_firebird, revisar el resto de librerias pdo ó firebird)

2 - Copiar librería fbclient.dll:
    Copiar el archivo fbclient.dll en C:/Windows/SysWOW64 y C:/Windows/System32

3 - En windows10 puede dar error de "PHP no se reconoce como comando interno o externo..." en algunos IDEs
    Ir a Equipo->propiedades->Configuración avanzada del sistema->Opciones avanzadas->Variables de entorno ->Variable: Path->Editar->Editar Texto
        Agregar al final de texto lo siguiente: ;C:/xampp/php/

Suerte!!

Comment: Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo para apoyarme, lastimosamente no logro hacer funcionar el driver, he realizado todo lo que me comentas pero no funciona, en phpinfo no me muestra el driver activado, tengo windows 10 de 64bits.

Comment: Para Windows 10, debes copiar el archivo fbclient.dll (C:/Firebird/Firebird_2_5/WOW64/fbclient.dll) en la siguiente ruta: C:/xampp/apache/bin y C:/Windows/SysWOW64